# Creating a new rdd from two different rdds

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two rdd as following:

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize([(('a','b'),10),(('c','d'),20)])
rdd2=sc.parallelize([('a',2),('b',3),('c',4)])
```

I need to make a new rdd as following: (value for `('a', 'b') => value(a,b)/value(a) => 10/2`

`[(('a','b'), 5.0), (('c','d'), 5.0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirement says that *you want the number rdd1 devided by the value from rdd2 which matches the key of rdd2 with first value of rdd1 key*.

If my understanding is correct then your requirement can be fulfilled by doing the following where rdd1 is transformed to make the first value as key so that join between two rdds can be perfomed.

```
rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x)).join(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], float(x[1][0][1]/x[1][1])))
#[(('a', 'b'), 5.0), (('c', 'd'), 5.0)]
```